# Gerry lied to us

Tags: wordplay, visual

Gerry, we don't want your distorted viewpoint. You misrepresented everything to us. Everything. You blew everything out of proportion.

I trust Jimmy and Arno more.  A little funny looking maybe, but they do tell it much more like it is.

What did Gerry do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question relates to

> map projections.

Specifically Gerry is:

> Gerardus Mercator, whose projection is way disproportionate in some cases (eg, Greenland and Africa being the same size)

Jimmy and Arno are:

> James Gall and Arno Peters, whose projection looks stretchy but maintains the ratio of various areas.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:
Gerry, Jimmy, and Arno all print photos. Jimmy and Arno slightly alter the sizes of the photos to fit the 4x6 frame, while Gerry blows the picture out of proportion to an 8x10 or poster size to the point that it's unrecognizable. **(WRONG)**

Take two:
They paint murals. Jimmy and Arno paint much more closely to reality than Gerry's more abstract art. **(STILL WRONG)**

Take three: I figured this answer was too literal to be true, but if you insist.

> They're all news reporters. Gerry always exaggerates the stories. Although Jimmy and Arno look funny, they tell the stories just how they happened.

With the influence of the Internet and everything, technically this one is bigger than murals.

Comment: While that's not what I had in mind, the discussion of proportion is the right thinking.  Gerry, Jimmy and Arno work at a larger scale though.  Think bigger.

Comment: Bigger. Hm. Try that second answer.

Comment: Metaphorically you're still just as correct, but literally wrong.  Jimmy and Arno did a better job than Gerry, but at what?  Larger.

Comment: Larger still? :/

Comment: Well, larger scale.

Comment: I like your thinking, but your first guess was best.  I could have mentioned that these are real people.